# pull to refresh with staggered grid view

Tags: android

I have used handmark pull to refresh library in staggered grid view.Its working fine but now i want that the grid view move itself vertically and when its moving even after that user should be able to pull the images which get hide due to movement of grid view. But it doesn't work.

code I used is:

```
pullToRefreshStaggeredGrid=(PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.staggeredGridView1);
        staggeredGridView=pullToRefreshStaggeredGrid.getRefreshableView();
        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin);

        staggeredGridView.setItemMargin(margin); // set the GridView margin

        staggeredGridView.setPadding(margin, 0, margin, 0); // have the margin on the sides as well 

        adapter = new StaggeredAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.imageView1,urls,imageLoader);

        new AsyncClass().execute(count);
}




AND ASYNC CLASS IS:



private class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>
    {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            publishProgress();

            return params[0];
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            staggeredGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count=result;
            Log.e("count","count"+count);
            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            final Handler handler=new Handler();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( 
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        final long t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {


                                    Log.e("timer","timer");
                                    staggeredGridView.scrollTo(0, count);
                                    count=count+10;
                                    pullToRefreshStaggeredGrid.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                            });

                            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-t0>5 * 1000)
                            {
                                Log.e("cancel","cancel");
                                timer.cancel();
                            }

                        }


                    },200,100
                    );
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Can you show us the logcat?

Comment: not getting any error...actually what i am trying to do is.u can say.auto scrolling ...when grid view get scrolled automaticaly .then some of images get hide.and when i pull grid view from top to bottom.even then images not visible.......hope so u get what i m trying to say.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new pull to refresh (https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) you can use custom ViewDelegate and check if first view in StaggeredGridView has position 0 and is scrolled to top (getTop() == sgv.getItemMargin()).